# Add custom folder shortcuts to places list

Tags: 12.04, places

Is there a way to add a folder to the **computer** list on my menu? 
I would like to add workbench.

I don't want to add it as a bookmark. I want it to appear in the same list as everything else.

[image]

Comment: Move to? Right-click, hover over 'Move to...' and choose computer.

Comment: I have 3 options in move to
- other pane (grayed out)
- home 
- desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the instructions outlined in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/292727/18487) - this solved the same problem I had.

Excerpts:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Remove the list you do not want. However, once you login again, it will reset, so

```
echo "enabled=false" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf
```

Answer (score 9):

The closest I've gotten is to add a folder to the bookmarks. Navigate into a directory and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then it'll get added to a "Bookmarks" sub-list below Places.

EDIT: On second glance, it is available from the "GEAR" menu on the upper-right corner of the window.